# Basic Question about Energy-Force Relationship

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

I was looking at the solution of a problem, and saw

$$\frac {dE}{dt}= \vec v\cdot \vec F$$

Where does that come from? I would've expected

$$\frac {dE}{dt}= m  v \cdot \dot v+ \frac {dU}{dt}$$

Comment: It would help if you defined the symbols.

Comment: Work done $= \vec{\rm  force} \cdot \vec {\rm displacement} = \vec F \cdot d\vec x$,  

rate of working $= \vec F \cdot d\vec x/ dt=\vec F \cdot \vec v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the potential $U$ is constant in both time and space then we have $\frac {dU}{dt} = 0$ and

$\displaystyle \frac {dE}{dt} = m \vec v \cdot \dot {\vec v}$

But $m \dot {\vec v} = m \vec a = \vec F$ so we have

$\displaystyle \frac {dE}{dt} = \vec v \cdot \vec F$

Comment: but if we are moving in a potential $U=U(x,y,z)$, then $\frac {dU}{dt}= \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} \dot x +\frac {\partial U}{\partial y}\dot y +\frac {\partial U}{\partial z}\dot z$, therefore wouldn't the term $\frac {dU}{dt}\neq 0$?

Comment: @gluon Yes, $U$ has to be constant in both time and space to remove the $\frac {dU}{dt}$ term. I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that an object is subject to a time independent potential $U$, so that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}$ vanishes. Then $U$ only depends on time via the position of the object and you can use the chain rule of differentiation to get $\frac{dE}{dt} = {\vec \nabla} U \cdot {\vec v} =  -{\vec F} \cdot {\vec v}$.